# Chrome refuses to refresh after being stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have 2 HTML pages that are served locally from a local file server (node.js)

Page A: includes a bug in the client side JavaScript, which freezes the page due to an infinite loop
Page B: does not include any bug

I first opened the Page A, after which my browser froze as expected, so I closed that window and tried opening page B, but chrome refused to load the page for several minutes.

When the browser is in this state, it seems to only block pages that are of the same origin, for example, other pages, like StackOverflow, load just fine.

Other observations I made:

- If I open page B on Safari instead of chrome, it loads just fine. So it can't be a server issue
- Page B still refused to load on chrome after ending the process of page A in the chrome task manager.
- Page B loads fine after waiting for about 5 minutes.

Is there any way of fresh-loading page B quickly?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with some legacy code, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I found out that if I kill the page process on task manager everything loads back fine.

Comment: I re-read my original post, I tried to reproduce it, but I think the issue is gone, after terminating the original page process of page A, page B loads fine.